# Tridion 2013 Site Edit don't load css in the preview on chrome

Tags: 2013, experience-manager, siteedit, chrome

The problem is only with Chrome (at least with the 48.0.2564.116 m version). We have "secure" content (SSL with particular certificate), and with Edge and Firefox after accept the risks and adding a exception, the page to edit shows perfect, with the styles, but don't with chrome, there the only one problem is that doesn't load the styles...

Any way, i dont know if the problem is because a fault in the configuration because in with edge and firefox works perfectly... Anyone more with this issue and any help?

Comment: Actualization: In Chrome, if i change the device to pe. IPAD... It works and loads the styles... but in desktop mode don't.

Answer (score 1):

Check for Tridion hotfixes for chrome browser on the SDLtridionworld site, there are chrome hotfixes for the cms that may also apply in your case.

Comment: the problem is that we have not the HR1.... is it mandatory?